# How to overcome the 126 character restriction for filepaths on 'LoadPicure' that exists since Windows update 1903

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

Existing VBA add-ins have started to fall over on this line if the `filepath` is longer than 126 characters. Shorter file paths are not an option, unfortunately.

`Set ImageControl.Picture = LoadPicture (FilepathLongerThan126CharsErrors)`

> Runtime Error '75' (File/Path access error)

The error does not occur if the file path is shortened to 125 characters.

We tried to set the RegKey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` to (1) but to no avail.

Machines that have not yet had the Windows 10 1903 update don't seem to be affected. The problem occurs mainly on Surface Laptops so far but also a few other PCs.

Comment: Can you try using the short path? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shortpath-property or don't you have control over what gets passed in?

Comment: Yes that works. Thanks! However, it's strange that this becomes now necessary when the character limit for filepaths should be around 256.  It means that we will have to change existing solutions that are rolled out at various clients for quite a few hundred users.Very annoying! Thanks for your tip though, much appreciated and a workable solution.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a folder on a lower level to shorten the path?

Answer (score 0):

Possible workarounds are listed below:

1. You may copy existing images into the `AppData` subfolder to make a path shortened.
2. Use the [ShortPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shortpath-property) property which returns the short path used by programs that require the earlier 8.3 file naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you Tim and Eugene. I am now working with the 'ShortPath'. 
However, the problem is still that the behaviour of this method has changed with the Windows 1903 update (from allowing 260 characters to now 126). There must be quite a few people out there scratching their heads why their codes are failing seemingly at random.

Thanks anyway. I'll put an error trap to feed the ShortPath through when needed.